# How to find maven dependency that comes somewhere from the parent pom?

Tags: maven, dependencies, dependency-management

I have a big maven project. `pom` file of the project has a parent `pom` which has a dependencies that have sometimes their parent `pom` defined inside.

In the `effective pom` of my project I see Lombok dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Is there any easy way to find a `pom` file in this complex hierarchy that declares this dependency?

Comment: have you tried mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=lombok ?

Comment: yes, it didn't help